# Syntax error on token ";", invalid AssignmentOperator

Tags: java, eclipse, assignment-operator

```java
private List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I have some bunch of codes, but this gave me an error.

I use Eclipse and it shows a red underline right under <;> character. I don't know why. Everything seems fine. This is the whole code:

```
public class Analyze {

    protected String text = null;

    public List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>(); // Error is right here.

    this.tokenize();

    public Analyze(String txt) {
        // This is the constructor. I will call the class outside with a variable just like method. Just like: Analyze aText = new Analyze("Some texts here.");
        // Then I will call the tokens variable inside the class. (Or am I just doing it wrong?)

        this.text = txt;
    }

    private List<String> tokenize() {
        // Some codes that changes the value of "tokens" variable.
    }
}
```

I had a look on internet and this platform, I generally found some logical operators like <, >, = etc. cause this problem but not **;**.

## Additional Edit

When I change the places of those lines like this:

```
public List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
protected String text = null; // Then error seems right here.
```

Comment: this.Analyze(); this is invalid line

Comment: Correct. That line needs to be inside some sort of method. Also, what did you mean to happen there? That method returns a value but you don't do anything with it.

Comment: **// Some Codes** area changes the value of private _tokens_ variable and returns it. (Actually I just saw that it seems really silly, I will edit the code.)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in `this.Analyze();`. It should be inside some method.

Though it's not clear what this line is supposed to do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `this.tokenize();` at the current position

you can write it like this but that will also not serve any purpose cause it returns the array list

```
public Analyze(String txt) {
    this.text = txt;
    this.tokenize();
}
```

Comment: I just edited the code. I made the _tokens_ public so that I can reach it outside of class.

Comment: location of your method call is in correct. you can not have method calls like this until they are in static block